# no such option: --no-install

Tags: python-2.7, installation, pip, gdal

I am trying to setup cartodb in ubuntu 12.04 by following https://github.com/danseely/cartodb-install/blob/master/DEV-INSTALLATION.md and as a part of the installation, there are some python dependencies to be installed.Below is a part which i tried

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
sudo pip install --no-install GDAL
```

While giving sudo pip install --no-install GDAL it is giving an error

```
no such option --no-install.
```

FYI i have python 2.7 dev version installed.I don't know whats wrong. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `--no-install` option has been [removed in pip version 7](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/).

The new option appears to be called `--download`, which takes a directory as argument:

```
sudo pip install --download /tmp/GDAL GDAL
```

For the `--no-download` option given a few lines later in the installation guide linked in your question, you'll have to try and do the following as alternative, since that is also deprecated:

```
pip install /tmp/GDAL
```

or similar, according to [this pip issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1345).

---

As of pip 8.0.0, `--download` has been deprecated. Instead, use

```
sudo pip download GDAL
```

(see the [release notes](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/)).

---

Since this seems to be an issue about grabbing the include dirs, have you tried using setting CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS instead? E.g.

```
export CFLAGS=/usr/include/gdal 
export CXXFLAGS=/usr/include/gdal 
sudo pip install GDAL
```

Not sure why the linked installation guide uses C_INCLUDE_PATH instead.

Also, this seems to be the usual kludginess you can run into, which is either because the OS decides to places package header files into a separate subdirectory, or because GDAL source code is not properly written to `#include <gdal/gdal.h>` etc. You may run into that more often, if you install more software.

Comment: Evert thanks for the reply. I tried sudo pip install unpack GDAL as you suggested but am getting the error 

  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement unpack (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for unpack. May be i think it is due to some SSL configuration.

Comment: @harinish That is because you run the command `sudo pip install unpack GDAL`, instead of `sudo pip unpack GDAL`.

Comment: ERROR: unknown command "unpack". Is there any way to solve this. Am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: My bad: unpack is suggested in the issue, but never implemented. It seems --download is the new way of doing this. See my updated answer.

Comment: Note that `pip install --download` was replaced in 10.0.0b1 (31-Mar-2018) by `pip download`, which includes a `--destination-directory` option. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#b1-2018-03-31

Comment: @AlejandroCDeBaca See the note between horizontal lines in the question. It's just that per version 10, `--download` has been completely removed instead of deprecated.