# Can't install coinbase API with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, coinbase-api

Python 3.6
pip3

Whenever I run

```
pip3 install coinbase
```

I get the error

```
c:\users\zac\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Even though the folder that has `io.h` is in my path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt`

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336153/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip/12550704#12550704)?

Comment: I tried and got the error pip install --no-install coinbase

Usage:
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --no-install

Comment: It seems that [--no-install option has been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207374/no-such-option-no-install#answer-33209099)

Comment: pip3 install download coinbase gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Define the below Environment variables and then run the pip command

```
INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64
```

(or)

Run the below command before running "pip3 install coinbase"

```
set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\<version>\ucrt
set LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\<version>\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\<version>\ucrt\x64
```

As the version changes path changes
For example: `version --> 10.0.10240.0`

```
set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
set LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64
```

Comment: I do this and get the same error. I also have version 10.0.15063.0, could this possibly be why? Also as in, I have both version 10.0.10240.0 and 10.0.15063.0

Comment: previously you have included in the path right?
please check the versions if there are any conflicts and change accordingly